# How create 2 identify fields in Mongodb-Ccsharp

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I would like to create 2 identify fields using C# mongo driver. The first id field is default mongo id and the second it unique integer id for each record/document.

```
public class Book
{
    [BsonId]
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }

    [BsonId(IdGenerator = typeof(IdGenerator<Book>))]
    public int BookId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

is it possible to do something like this?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by identity fields.  You can set your fields to anything you like, including ObjectIds.  If you would like to have multiple fields with object IDs in them, that is totally appropriate, just use the c# driver to generate an OID(object ID) and set whatever field you would like to that OID.  Let me know if you would like me to expand further upon this.

Comment: @ACE thanks for you answer, but i wanna 2 fields, one of them ObjectId field which populated from MongoDB, the second will be Integer field with auto increment.

Answer (score 1):

The C# driver will generate the first one (the Id) for you automatically, but the second one (the BookId) is just another data field to the driver, so it would be the application's responsibility to generate the next available unique BookId.

One way I have seen people generate the next available custom integer Id is by using a sequences collection to keep track of the next available Id. This is how it would look using the MongoDB shell:

```
db.sequences.insert({ _id : "BookId", nextId : 1 })
db.sequences.find()
{ "_id" : "BookId", "nextId" : 1 }
var result = db.sequences.findAndModify({
    query : { _id : "BookId" },
    update : { $inc : { nextId : 1 }}
    })
result
{ "_id" : "BookId", "nextId" : 1 }
 db.sequences.find()
{ "_id" : "BookId", "nextId" : 2 }
```

This does require an extra round trip to the database to find the next available Id.